# Can not access game object added in overlay scene

Tags: python, game-engine, objects

I have a text object in a scene. That scene is added at the start of the game as an overlay scene. Whenever I try to access the text object, named "HUD.text" (to change the game text) the bge returns:

> `Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "path\to\my\script.py", line 71,
>   in main
>       HUDtext = hud.objects['HUD.text']
>   KeyError: "CList[key]: ''HUD.text'' key not in list"`

Which if I'm understanding it right means the object 'HUD.text' is not available for the game engine.

I have checked that the overlay scene is being added correctly (it is), and if I print all the objects in that scene 'HUD.text' is in the array.

I add the overlay scene with this line in a script that runs once at game start. `bge.logic.addScene('hud', 1)`

hud is defined by `hud = bge.logic.getSceneList()[-1]`

`print(hud.name)` outputs `hud`

`print(hud.objects)` outputs `[Plane, HUD.text, Camera.001]`

Is there something I have to do to make objects added in a overlay scene available? Or is there some huge delay in the time it takes to add the scene?

**[Here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/422/)** is an example blend file showing the error.

Comment: I can't see a problem. I suggest to create a demo.blend and post it. Remark: while this is an interesting problem, changing text goes very well with messages ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file works for me in 2.78, after pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> I see text saying "123".

I still get the error the first time hud.objects is accessed, on the same tic as the scene is added.  The [documentation explains](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.logic.html?highlight=bge%20scene#bge.logic.addScene):

> This function is not effective immediately, the scene is queued and **added on the next logic cycle** where it will be available from getSceneList.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

To avoid this error, you could do something like:

```
def main(cont):
    own = cont.owner

    if "scene_init" not in own:
        own["scene_init"] = True
        bge.logic.addScene('hud',1)
    else:
        hud = bge.logic.getSceneList()[-1]
        HUDtext = hud.objects['HUD.text']
        print(HUDtext.text)
        HUDtext['Text'] = '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use a variable for KX_GameObject that contains characters like ".", ",", "!" etc. You must use only lowercase and uppercase letters and numbers. In this case you must do something like:

```
HUDtext = hud.ojects["HUD.text"]
```

or

```
HUD_text = hud.objects["HUD.text"]
```

You can use any variable name that contains only letters and numbers. Note that it can't start with number.

Comment: sorry that is not the issue at all. I changed the var name when copying in to my question, not thinking that it was invalid.

Comment: Actually I doubt if overlay scene objects are aviable, but I really don't know it - haven't used yet. If they are aviable, than gamesystem classes or glbalDict are not needed to be updated every frame, just when switching scenes.

Comment: At least now, the above variable names are correct and the error belongs to the dictionary access (not variable declaration).